# "Proxying http from https using two certificates"

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

I've been trying to make work "Proxying http from https using two certificates" with the last version of Nodejs currently available (v0.10.2) but I've not been able to do it.

I did this with one certificate and it works:

```
var https = require("https"),
path = require("path"),
http = require("http"),
fs = require("fs"),
httpProxy = require("http-proxy"),
crypto = require("crypto");

//
// Proxy options
//
var options = {
https: {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ryans-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ryans-cert.pem')
},
hostnameOnly: true,
router: {
  'foobar.com': '127.0.0.1:8005',
}
};

//
// Create a standalone HTTPS proxy server
//
httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(8002);

//
// Create the target HTTPS server
//
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('hello https\n');
  res.end();
}).listen(8005);
```

Testing it It works perfectly:

> curl -k https://foobar.com:8002
>   hello https

However I was trying to do something if Ihave to use two virtual host and two different certificates but I couldn't make it work (this is an example of syntax that I have tried):

```
var https = require("https"),
path = require("path"),
http = require("http"),
httpProxy = require("http-proxy"),
fs = require("fs"),
crypto = require("crypto");

//
// generic function to load the credentials context from disk
//
function getCredentialsContext () {
return crypto.createCredentials({
  key: fs.readFileSync('ryans-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ryans-cert.pem')
}).context;
}

//
// A certificate per domain hash
//
var certs = {
  "foobar.com": getCredentialsContext(),
};

//
// Proxy options
//
var options = {
https: {
  SNICallback: function (hostname) {
  return certs[hostname];
}
},
hostnameOnly: true,
router: {
'foobar.com': '127.0.0.1:8005',
}
};

//
// Create a standalone HTTPS proxy server
//
httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(8002);

//
// Create the target HTTPS server
//
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
res.write('hello https\n');
res.end();
}).listen(8005);
```

These are the logs with this last example:

```
tls.js:1046
throw new Error('Missing PFX or certificate + private key.');
^
Error: Missing PFX or certificate + private key.
at Server (tls.js:1046:11)
at new Server (https.js:35:14)
at Object.exports.createServer (https.js:54:10)
at Object.exports.createServer (node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy.js:178:13)
at Object. (nodejs_test/ssl_test2.js:43:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

It seems it does not recognize the keys. Could it be because of the function crypto.createCredentials?

I created the key and the certificate as it says in the nodejs documentation: http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html:

```
   openssl genrsa -out ryans-key.pem 1024
   openssl req -new -key ryans-key.pem -out ryans-csr.pem
   openssl x509 -req -in ryans-csr.pem -signkey ryans-key.pem -out ryans-cert.pem
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the default certificate and key for the server to use. You need to add the cert and key properties in the options object as you had for the normal https proxy, e.g.:

```
var options = {
    https: {
        SNICallback: function (hostname) {
            return certs[hostname];
        },
        key: fs.readFileSync('ryans-key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('ryans-cert.pem'),
    },
    hostnameOnly: true,
    router: {
        'foobar.com': '127.0.0.1:8005',
    }
};
```